# Возможно ли найти ключ шифрования при помощи xor?

Tags: битовые-операции

Есть система уравнений:

```
x = a xor b;
y = b xor c;
```

если известны только x и y, возможно ли узнать b?

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Из-за свойства коммутативности у нас всегда будет две пары. Это просто проверить.

При x = 1, y = 0:

```
1 = 1 xor 0
0 = 0 xor 0
```

или

```
1 = 0 xor 1
0 = 1 xor 1
```

При x = 1, y = 1:

```
1 = 1 xor 0
1 = 0 xor 1
```

или

```
1 = 0 xor 1
1 = 1 xor 0
```

и т.д.

Comment: Скажите, если изменить немного формулу, возможно ли будет решить уравнение? К примеру для y операцию xor заменить на что-то другое.

Comment: @user262975 Если в одном уравнении заменить логическую функцию, то нет. Можно только, зная 4 переменные, определить пятую.

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Пусть x=1 и y=1
Возможны варианты

b=1 a=0 c=0

b=0 a=1 c=1